# Where do I find evidence of what happened to Ambassador Osoba's son?

Tags: mass-effect-3

The mission **Benning: Evidence** says that I need to find evidence of what happened to Ambassador Osoba's son, who went missing on Benning. However, when I hover over the systems in my galaxy map, none of them get tagged with this quest, so I don't know where I need to go for it.

[image]

> Where can I find evidence about Ambassador Osoba's missing son?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can complete this during the N7 mission **Cerberus Abduction**, the [Mass Effect Wiki has a brief "walkthrough"](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/Benning:_Evidence). Note if you're lazy or miss the dog tags (the evidence you need) you can just buy them later on.

From the Wiki:

> On the N7: Cerberus Abductions mission, look for dogtags on the ground near a pillar where your first objective is. Return to the Citadel and give the dogtags to Dominic Osoba to finish the quest.
>
> If you miss the dogtags during N7: Cerberus Abductions you can purchase the dogtags from the Spectre operation room for 1000 credits and then present them to Osoba to complete the mission.

Answer (score 3):

You won't be able to complete this one until you've progressed a bit further in the game from when you first acquire it.

Once you gain the storyline mission **Attican Traverse: Krogan Team**, the side quest **N7: Cerberus Abduction** will unlock. When you visit the required planet, you'll find his sons dogtags lying on the ground early on.